# google test fixture one time action

Tags: googletest, fixtures

I've started to use google test fixture and
in my test suite I need to open/close a file only once , open the file before the first test start and close it after that the last test has been executed.
I wonder if there is a method of the fixture that
allow to do an action only ones at the beginning/end of the test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `static` member variable to hold file object and define it outside the `fixture class`.

After that, define `static void SetUpTestSuite()` and use it to open your file and `static void TearDownTestSuite()` to close your file.

google test will call `SetUpTestSuite()` before first test and `TearDownTestSuite()` after last test.

You can also check [Sharing Resources Between Tests in the Same Test Suite](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite) from the official documentation